# Cannot disable buttons when the time slots are unavailable

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to disable the buttons with the time slots that are unavailable based on the timetable. But when I try to debug these lines of codes, the buttons are still enabled, what codes that I have typed are wrong?

```
private void LoadMonday(LoadOperation<TimeTable> objTT)
    {
        List<TimeTableInfo> listTT = new List<TimeTableInfo>();

        foreach (var item in objTT.Entities)
        {
            listTT.Add(new TimeTableInfo()
                {
                    TimeTableID = item.TimeTableID,
                    LecturerID = item.LecturerID,
                    Course = item.Course,
                    ClassStartTime = (DateTime)item.ClassStartTime,
                    ClassEndTime = (DateTime)item.ClassEndTime,
                    ClassVenue = item.ClassVenue
                });
        }

        DateTime monday = GetDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
        string monDate = monday.ToShortDateString();
        Button[] btnMonday = new Button[20];

        for (int a = 0; a < 20; a++)
        {
            btnMonday[a] = new Button();
            btnMonday[a].Height = 24;
            btnMonday[a].Width = 160;
            btnMonday[a].HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            btnMonday[a].VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            btnMonday[a].Content = monDate + " " + timeslot[a];
            btnMonday[a].FontFamily = new FontFamily("eurostile");
            btnMonday[a].FontSize = 14;

            foreach (var checkClass in listTT)
            {
                DateTime startTime = checkClass.ClassStartTime;
                DateTime endTime = checkClass.ClassEndTime;
                DateTime temp;

                if (DateTime.TryParse(btnMonday[a].Content.ToString(), out temp))
                {
                    DateTime cmpTime = DateTime.Parse(btnMonday[a].Content.ToString());
                    var halfHour = GetHalfHour(startTime, endTime);

                    foreach (var period in halfHour)
                    {
                        int result = DateTime.Compare(cmpTime, period);
                        if (result == 0)
                        {
                            btnMonday[a].IsEnabled = false;
                            btnMonday[a].Content = checkClass.Course + " at " + checkClass.ClassVenue;
                            btnMonday[a].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            btnMonday[a].Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            Grid.SetColumn(btnMonday[a], 1);
            Grid.SetRow(btnMonday[a], a + 1);
            btnMonday[a].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btnMonday_Click);
            TimeSlotLayoutRoot.Children.Add(btnMonday[a]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is no problem,

- try to check your database retrieve query
- ReBuild Solution always (while silverlight used to pre-build and will not re-bake new file
- Use IE to debug line by line

let me know if any other problem couldn't solve. share more details of how you does in db entry retrieving.